# Modify Enum Associated Values

Tags: swift, enums

is any way to modify enum's asssociated values in Swift? I do it this way, but every time I have to override whole object. It's not elegant.

```
    switch option {
        case .Days(let choices):
            var newChoices = choices

            ...

            self.days = Option.Days(newChoices)

        default:
            break
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to modify the associated value of enum case, but you can use a type with reference-semantics (i.e. *class*) to attach a mutable value inside of a container like so:

```
class Box<T>: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var value: T
    var debugDescription: String { return "\(value)" }
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}

enum X {
    case A(Box<Int>), B(Box<String>)
}

let x = X.A(Box(1))
let y = X.B(Box("xxx"))

print(x, y) // A(1) B(xxx)

if case let X.A(box) = x {
    box.value = 2
}

if case let X.B(box) = y {
    box.value = "yyy"
}

print(x, y) // A(2) B(yyy)
```

Though, it doesn't look very elegant to me.